# Django: TypeError: XXX() got multiple values for argument 'chat_id'

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django with Celery and getting this error:

`TypeError: get_response() got multiple values for argument 'chat_id'`

I'm calling the function via:

```
i = get_response.delay(chat_id=chat_id, is_first_message=is_first_message,question=question,user_id=user_id)
```

and the function header is:

```
@shared_task(bind=True)
def get_response(chat_id: int, is_first_message: bool,
                     question:str,user_id:int) -> str:
```

I tried running a print(chat_id) but this only confirmed the field was a single integer.

Edit. Full trace:

```
[03/Jul/2023 13:52:16] ERROR "django.request" Internal Server Error: /chat/chat/1/283/new_message/
project      | Traceback (most recent call last):
project      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
project      |     response = get_response(request)
project      |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
project      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
project      |     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
project      |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
project      |   File "/code/apps/chat/views.py", line 82, in new_message
project      |     i = get_response.delay(chat_id=chat_id, is_first_message=is_first_message,question=question,user_id=user_id)
project      |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
project      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 425, in delay
project      |     return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
project      |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
project      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 540, in apply_async
project      |     check_arguments(*(args or ()), **(kwargs or {}))
project      | TypeError: get_response() got multiple values for argument 'chat_id'
project      | [03/Jul/2023 13:52:16] ERROR "django.server" "POST /chat/chat/1/283/new_message/ HTTP/1.1" 500 87645
```

Comment: Please share the full traceback.

Comment: can you share the line above `get_response` (the decorator you use on `get_response`)?

Comment: According to the traceback you call `get_reponse.delay`. There's a missing "s" in "response". Could it be that you have two functions `get_reponse` and `get_response` and they have different parameters?

Comment: Know that was me typing it wrong when i pasted the traceback for you - the actual name was a lot longer so I was trying to simplify it. Let me correct...

Comment: @WillemVOsupportsmodstrike I've added a crucial bit of info .. above the function def it had the decorator `'@shared_task(bind=True)'`  -- this i thin is causing it, just need to figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should leave the `bind=True` out, indeed:

```
@shared_task  # 🖘 no bind=True
def get_response(
    chat_id: int, is_first_message: bool, question: str, user_id: int
) -> str:
    # …
    pass
```

indeed, with [*bound tasks* <sup>[celery-doc]</sup>](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#bound-tasks) the task instance is passed as first parameter, so you should either add `self` (or `task` or some other parameter) as first parameter, or remove the `bind=True`, since you don't seem to use it in your function anyway.